# How to develop a 3-D svg dynamic file using Blender

Tags: svg

My challenge is **not** Swift. My challenge is the development of the 3-D svg dynamic file using Blender.

I have worked with Blender a small amount and its use is currently intimidating

**I am developing a Game Controller activated game called Croquet Player.**

The proposed game sequence is as follows:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brbqq.png) Using Swift, the Game Controller moves the Player toward the Ball = ***done***

[2] The  dynamic svg Blender file takes over and rotates the Player such that his head is always facing the Ball **and** moves the Mallet in such a way that the flat head of the Mallet is pointed at the Ball = ***not done***

[3] When the Game Controller moves the Player such that the Mallet eventually contacts the Ball, the Swift code hits the Ball and it moves = ***done***

And the above sequence starts over: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brbqq.png) move Player toward Ball, [2] rotate the Player toward the Ball as it’s moving toward the Ball, **and** repoint Mallet toward the Ball, [3] upon the Mallet actually contacting the Ball, hit it.

Here is a screen shot of a sample of the Player’s & Mallet’s orientations as I just described:

[image: sample orientations]

Please note this is just a screen shot that illustrates the above rotation and re-positioning goals with various angles.

Also note, that for obvious reasons I am seeking **one** svg whose imbedded code does the Player rotation and Mallet re-positioning for me. In addition, **one** svg negates the necessity of 8 static poses. One svg provides a seeming infinite number of poses.

And lastly, please be assured I have reviewed seemingly countless videos describing Blender. When I stated above **intimidating**, that was a large intimidation to the point of being almost un-understandable.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Blender expert who in person and in the space of 10 minutes could say "John, here's how to do it".

Oh, how I wish.

Comment: I think you're very unlikely to get any answers here as your question is well outside the remit of this Q&A site! See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: John, I just clicked on your link and I just do **not** see any access to posting this question. If this is accurate, I guess I am just on my own

Comment: Blender seems like the wrong tool for this. It mainly outputs rendered raster files, it doesn't excel at vector files, even less dynamic ones.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, Duarte

Comment: @JohnLove You're effectively asking multiple questions about how to do things in Blender which is discouraged in a single question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Guidance is one thing. Nevertheless, a good question may consist of 2 parts especially when these 2 parts are tightly integrated as they are in my case. There is a whole slew of examples, notably in Quantum Mechanics and mathematics

Comment: Anyway, as already stated, I will continue on my own. Bye!

Comment: SVG files are inherently two dimensional. If such effect is even possible, it would likely be through faking the transform with 2d distortions. To my limited knowledge that would only be possible through scripting them using something like Javascript or SMIL, and as far as I know there are no graphical editors to make these types of dynamic SVG animations through a GUI

Comment: *"The dynamic svg Blender file[…]"* - what do you mean by this? I searched for `dynamic svg file` and couldn't find anything that would seem relevant. Also I don't understand the rest of the sentence *"[…]takes over[…]"* - how could a file take over? A Blender file can possibly be designed to offer an application-like interface, but Blender is far from satisfactory in providing such functionalities (I know some features are planned to make it better, "starting files" or something like that). In the past (previous Blender versions) there was BGE…

Comment: So I am back to using Swift to select between multiple static poses. Nothing wrong with that EXCEPT I would be stuck with having to convert say 10-20. 2D pngs to 3D. For example 1 3D image for every 5 degrees of rotation

Comment: Quite honestly I do not know how to do the above conversion in Blender. The mountain of videos go rapid fire to the verge of being UNunderstandable. I am not blessed with a in person Blender expert who could lean over my shoulder to show me in 10 minutes how to do that. 10 lousy minutes